# Functions and Relations - Help!

Tags: functions

Given that : $$\begin{align} &f: D_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ & g: D_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \end{align} $$

Find, $f + g : D_1 \cap D_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f+g$ will be defined as $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for all $x\in D_1\cap D_2$.

Comment: Oh! Got my mistake. Thanks! :)